# php and mySQL date doesn't work - something to do with american vs european structure?

Tags: php, mysql, date, phpmyadmin

I have some php code that is doing a query on mySQL database - If I do the query in phpmyadmin it works - but if I do the same search in php it doesn't work

copied from phpmyadmin works fine returns all the rows

```
SELECT * FROM contract WHERE DATE(`fdos`) >= '2013-05-01' And DATE(`fdos`) <= '2013-05-09'
```

my php code doesnt work  (neither query)  only returns 3 of 30 rows that it should.  The format of the date cannot change that is how I _GET the data.

```
$startdate = "2013-05-01";
$enddate = "2013-06-01";
function getAllContracts($startdate, $enddate)
{
$sd = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace("-","/",$startdate)));
$ed = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace("-","/",$enddate)));
$query1="SELECT * FROM contract WHERE DATE(`fdos`) >= '$sd' And  DATE(`fdos`) <= '$ed'";
$query2="SELECT * FROM contract WHERE DATE(`fdos`) >= Date('$startdate') And     DATE(`fdos`) <= Date('$enddate')";
}
```

Other thing to add is that mysql I store the date as a text in this format '2013-05-01' and that is why i have to call the DATE

Comment: is that supposed to be 05th january - 05th september?

Comment: ? not sure where you got september... but thats may 1st 2013 to june 1st 2013

Comment: The variables $startdate and $enddate, where they come from? A form submit?

Comment: mysql directly supports only ONE date format: `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`. national formats are irrelevant. either you format a date into mysql's standard, or you get undefined results. You are reformatting your date strings yyyy-mm-dd to yyyy/mm/dd, which is **NOT** a valid mysql date, so you'll be getting nulls or default dates everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put " around this variables

```
$startdate = "2013-05-01";
$enddate = "2013-06-01";
```

Comment: i think he's referring to number of results, this is a typo though

Comment: I do - Sorry copy paste into here - pretty sure that would give a syntax error so wouldn't even be possible

Comment: Try this way:

$startdate = "2013-05-01";
$enddate = "2013-06-01";
function getAllContracts($startdate, $enddate)
{
$query1="SELECT * FROM contract WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`fdos`,'%Y-%m-%d') >= STR_TO_DATE($startdate,'%Y-%m-%d') And  STR_TO_DATE(`fdos`,'%Y-%m-%d') <= STR_TO_DATE($enddate,'%Y-%m-%d')";
$query2="SELECT * FROM contract WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`fdos`,'%Y-%m-%d') >= STR_TO_DATE($startdate,'%Y-%m-%d') And STR_TO_DATE(`fdos`,'%Y-%m-%d') <= STR_TO_DATE($enddate,'%Y-%m-%d')";
}

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is in the query itself, try to use [`BETWEEN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html) for comaprison

```
$query1="SELECT * FROM contract WHERE DATE(`fdos`) BETWEEN '$sd' AND '$ed'";
```